# is it safe to implement custom way of storing cookie in android?

Tags: android, cookies, session-management

i want to store session information in android application temporarily (as long as application is running). i am sending real-time data to node.js server from android client using Custom Protocol (over UDP). Along with this data i will send cookie (or session string unique to each user) to server for further processing. is this a safe way to store cookie in ram. Is this safe for users?

I am new to this security stuff so i want help. if i have missed any information i am willing to add it.

Answer (score 1):

> is this a safe way to store cookie in ram

How do you know it will be stored in RAM?

What is your definition of safe?

> Custom Protocol (over UDP)

Unless that's using DTLS it's probably not safe.

There are ways of implementing a secure model around this - the concept of storing session data client side is not new - but you also have big potential issues around authenticity (i.e. preventing client side tampering).

Comment: i would store cookie in a variable so as long as the app is running the variable will have the cookie value in ram.

Comment: No - the browser deals with the cookie and decides where to store it. If you copy that to a javascript variable, then it is **likely** that the **copy** will only be stored in RAM (but far from certain).

Comment: i am making android application as mentioned in question.

Comment: Doesn't matter. There are 4 possible ways to implement this - using the embedded browser in dalvik, using a third party HTTP component in Dalvik or as an HTML5 app - all of which effectively mean you are using a browser. The fourth option would be that that you are writing your own HTTP stack from scratch - which would be very silly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of how it's stored I find it much more alarming that it's transmitted over a custom network protocol. It might either be completely unencrypted or encrypted with a homespun implementation. That's how you are really going to leak the cookies.

Comment: i am going to implement a DTLS and TLS channel for transferring cookies and data to client. so will it be considered secured?